# remove Mouse Over events to hide/unhide dock

Tags: macos, osx-lion, dock

I have been googling around to find a way to remove the dock on a Mac OSX Lion. However, I understand that there could be complications in retrieving minimized windows. So disabling it completely is not an option.

However, I would like it if the mouse over events did nothing to hide or unhide the dock. I find that the keyboard shortcut (Command + Option + D) works fine for me.

I haven't seen anyone ask for removal of the dock this way specifically, if so then I apologize for the duplicate question. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you want to show and hide the Dock by pressing `Cmd-Opt-D`, instead of moving the mouse to the screen border?

Comment: Thats correct. I can already use the shortcut but I want to make it so the mouse over just doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I would ever use it, but I am definitely curious now :)

Comment: There have been times where I use the marquee tool in photoshop near the bottom of the screen and the dock opens on me because my mouse got too close to it. Thats why I want to remove this functionality. Plus I never really use the dock anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a hidden preference for the delay before the animation starts:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 9999999
osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'
```

It doesn't affect full screen windows though.

This would increase the delay to about a second:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0.5
```

Comment: The problem with delaying it for a large amount of time would make it appear really slow when I need it for using the shortcut command.

Comment: Actually never mind. It worked. At least for now. I forgot the kill dock command after. I don't know what I was talking about there. I thought you were referring to the time-modifier which is different. Just to clarify I can use the shortcut command and it works right away whereas the mouse over takes forever. Thanks.